# Flutter iOS app Throws fatal exception missing opencv.h

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, opencv, frameworks

Nowadays I start working on opencv development with flutter. But I could not find useful tutorials and trying to implement myself. But stucks in the first step. I created a plugin and tried to integrate with ffi. But it throws fatal exception "opencv2/opencv.h file not found".

- Downloaded iOS pack 4.5.1  from [opencvreleases](https://opencv.org/releases/)
- Added to frameworks and embedded content in Xcode
- Fatal exception "opencv2/opencv.h file not found"

What is missing in my case?

[image: opencv2.frameworkdesktop]
[image: addedto_frameworks]

Comment: Are you sure the installation is done ?

Comment: I am not really sure on that but browser shows as finished. Are you referring "waiting" on the first screenshot?